# How do you take a square root of a matrix that contains zeros in python?

Tags: python

let's say we want to compute the square root of the identity matrix, how would you do in python? I have tried numpy.sqrt() but it didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by square root of a matrix? Can you give a small example for reference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, I mean square root the matrix element-wise. sqrt([0 4 9]) = [0 2 3]

Comment: Calculate the square root of the identity matrix certainly doesn't work, because the result is obviously still the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this element wise you can use

```
import numpy as np
my_matrix = np.array([0, 4, 9])
sqrt_my_matrix = np.sqrt(my_matrix)
print(sqrt_my_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
my_matrix = np.array([[1.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0]])

np.sqrt(my_matrix.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a package called [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/index.html). See the code below:

```
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm
my_matrix = np.array([[1.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0]])
sqrt_my_matrix = sqrtm(my_matrix)
```